# Cannot add component to BorderLayout Container without constraint parameter

Tags: codenameone

I do feeling difficulty over adding Layout Constraint of a button or container . I got the above error while i added the following order .

```
Container1.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // Container1 has Borderlayout as Layout Property .
```

My Button has a property of LayoutConstraint : West . 
When i addCompnent button into Container1 , i got the above error ..

Please suggest me on how to set LayoutConstraint property as well ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
 Container1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 Container1.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, myComponent);
```

Works as advertised.